# Facebook Sdk Login with new Activity Result API

Tags: android, facebook, registerforactivityresult

I couldn't manage to callback result with activity result API since Facebook SDK itself starts the activity for facebook login. When I try to write contract, I dont know what should I provide as a intent. I end up with opening a blank activity via contract and get result back when that activity is destroyed. In summary I dont know how to call the statement below with new Activity Result API. Any idea about that ? I also checked whether any updates from facebook API,but no luck for that.

```
mFacebookCallbackManager.onActivityResult(1001, resultCode, intent)
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you are going to succeed trying to integrate Facebook Login with the new Activity Contracts API.

The reason is very simple: Facebook request that you pass the `requestCode` into the call to `callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)` and the `requestCode` is managed by the ActivityContracts API, so you don't have access to it.

I don't know if Facebook have plans to integrate it Login API with this new Activity Contracts API (it would be awesome if they do) since they use that `requestCode` to track the instance of the `CallbackManagerImpl` that needs to be called after you pass the result in `onActivityResult`.

Comment: Hi guys, did they get it to work with the new apis